# Im trying to find out the problem to my code. I just fixed one in another code but now i have error CS0101 & CS0111

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently just solved one problem to my other code but this one had 2 problems. I have two errors saying "Assets/Exit.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'Exit'" & "Assets/Exit.cs(12,19): error CS0111: Type 'Exit' already defines a member called 'OnTriggerEnter2D' with the same parameter types". Ive been looking through my code to define my problem but i cant seem to find it as im still a beginner.

The code i used was

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Exit : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string sceneName;
    [SerializeField] private string newScenePw; 

    private void  OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            PlayerMovement.instance.scenePw = newScenePw;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate the help as i have a due date for releasing the first version of my game.

Comment: Did you happen to make a copy of your script by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Two things immediately pop out at me with this.

1. The compiler seems to think every declaration you made in your file is a duplicate.
2. No other file has this problem.

These symptoms are quite similar to what happens if you duplicate a class in the same file. The compiler will complain about the duplicate class name, but will still evaluate the contents for errors, and find that the functions inside the two classes are also duplicates. The latter is still done because the compiler does not know if you had wanted to make the classes partial.

I think that if the classes were duplicated in the same file, you would have noticed. However, two classes do not have to be in the same file to conflict with each other. Therefore, though it is impossible to say with complete certainty, my best guess is that your code is fine, and there is simply another version of the class elsewhere, in a different file.

This could be because you accidentally duplicated the file itself, but also could be because you accidentally copied the code inside the file and (somehow) accidentally appended it to the end of another file.

Such a duplicate can be easily located. Personally, I'd think that the simplest method would be do find all instances of the string "class Exit". Press Ctrl+F to do such a search in Visual Studio 2022.

It may be possible that the conflicting file may somehow be hidden my Visual Studio's explorer. However, I am 99% sure that Visual Studio's Find-and-Replace search also searches in hidden files, so this wouldn't be an issue, even in the improbable case that it is a possibility.

Happy coding! :)